# (JAVA) Tab declaration error ( using a class tab in constructor )

Tags: java, constructor, tabs

I have a problem with a declaration of `tab` in Java, I'm declaring a new array `tab` in a class and I want to use it in the constructor and then return the constructor's `tab` in a method, but I have problem with the `tab` declaration ( compiler error ). What's wrong here ?

```
class pascal5 {
int[] tab;
int prev1, prev2;

pascal5(int n) {
    tab[]=new int[n+1];

    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        for(int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
            if (k == 0) {
                tab[k] = 1;
                prev2 = 1;
            } else {
                prev1 = tab[k-1] + tab[k];
                tab[k-1] = prev2;
                prev2 = prev1;
            }
        }
    }
}

   int wspolczynnik(int m) {
   return tab[m];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**you cannot use the brackets [] after declaring the array just use the name of array to assign a new Array**

Replace this line `tab[]=new int[n+1];`
with `tab = new int[n+1];`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the statement:

```
tab[] = new int[n+1];
```

Instead, use:

```
tab = new int[n+1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initialising your `tab` in wrong way inside the constructor,

Do it like this,

```
tab = new int[n+1];
```

For more info on Arrays, check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

You can also declare your array like this:

```
int[] tab = new int[3];
int[] tab = {1,2,3};
int[] tab = new int[]{1,2,3};
```